# Custom spell checker

Tags: c#

I want this code to return true when there is no matching word.
The input:
`string1: badc string2: abc`

```
public static bool NotMatching(string a, string b)
{
    const int n = 3;
    int count = 0;
    if (a == b)
    {
        return false;
    }

    char[] chars1 = a.ToCharArray();
    char[] chars2 = b.ToCharArray();

    // take the minimum length
    int length = chars1.Length >= chars2.Length ? chars2.Length : chars1.Length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (chars1[i] != chars2[i])
        {
            if (count > n)
            {
                return true;
            }

            count++;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

It only works if the number of characters that don't match is known.
I want it to work in any situation.

Here are the inputs:

```
string[] phrase = "Acetsa e un texzt excelent da tet".Split();
string[] validWords = "acesta e un text de test".Split();
```

ant the output that I want:

```
acetsa: acesta
texzt: text
excelent: (there are no suggestions) // this is the word that has no suggestions
da: de
tet: text
tet: test
```

Comment: Why can't you try string1.contains(string2) ?

Comment: Or check if(s1.IndexOf(s2) == -1)

Comment: **@Szilágyi Ignác**: What is not clear here is the type of comparison that you want to make. Is it comparing two strings to see if there are differences? Is it determining if a substring is **in** the input string?

Comment: Unrelated: you may also want to consider using `Span<char>`. Especially if this is going to be executed a lot.

Comment: After edit: that looks more like a spell checker and would therefore require a more complicated logic.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static bool NotMatching(string a, string b)
{
    var (shorter, longer) = a.Length > b.Length ? (b, a) : (a, b);
    return !longer.Contains(shorter);
}
```

Edit:
After your question update this appears to be a completely different problem. I'd point you towards Levenshtein distance algorithm, which applied word by word to your problem should lead to a viable solution.
Wiki article contains pseudo-code implementation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance